# Attempting to automatically crop to data within a List and convert that to Image

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image that I initialized to be all 0 values.

```
img.Image onlyDog = img.Image.from(decodedImage);    // decodedImage is of size 720, 1080
// reset all pixels to 0.
img.fill(onlyDog, img.Color.fromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

The full size of the `onlyDog` image is `720 x 1080`. But a small portion of this image has been give values based on an if condition.

To get to the pixel level I had to do:

```
// get pixel level information for this image via getBytes()
    var pixels = decodedImage.getBytes();
    // do same for the dog image
    var dogPixels = onlyDog.getBytes();
```

The pixels I need are given values in the following loop:

```
// get pixel level information for this image via getBytes()
    var pixels = decodedImage.getBytes();
    // do same for the dog image
    var dogPixels = onlyDog.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length - 4; i += 4) {
      //pixels are in format RGBA

      var pixelColor = [pixels[i], pixels[i + 1], pixels[i + 2], pixels[i + 3]];
      var dogColor = [44, 232, 128, 255];

      if (listEquals(pixelColor, dogColor)){
        dogPixels[i] = pixels[i];      // R
        dogPixels[i + 1] = pixels[i + 1];    // G
        dogPixels[i + 2] = pixels[i + 2];    // B
        dogPixels[i + 3] = 255;  // A - keep this at max as this is the effect I want
      }
    }
```

Now, unlike python and other languages, images are not stored in clean `[row x column]` format but rather as a List so this makes it even more difficult to get the exact coordinates of the pixels set. What I want to do is to crop to the content and not return the massive space of emty `[0,0,0,0]` data.

**What I tried:**

I created a dynamic list and added any pixels that are not zero, this would basically extract only the meaningful content from `onlyDog`:

```
List<int> contentPixelList = [];
    // below for loop to look for cropping to content
    for (int i = 0; i < dogPixels.length - 4; i += 4) {
      var pixelColor = [dogPixels[i], dogPixels[i + 1], dogPixels[i + 2], dogPixels[i + 3]];
      if (!listEquals(pixelColor, [0, 0, 0, 0])){
        contentPixelList.add(dogPixels[i]);
        contentPixelList.add(dogPixels[i+1]);
        contentPixelList.add(dogPixels[i+2]);
        contentPixelList.add(dogPixels[i+3]);
        //print(dogPixels[i]);
      }
    }
```

I then converted this to a fixed List as we get an error if an `Image` is created from a `growableList`.

```
List<int> fixedListContent = new List<int>.from(contentPixelList, growable: false);
```

And an Image is created from this:

```
Uint8List dogCropList = new Uint8List.fromList(fixedListContent);
    //no image from above list
    img.Image dogCropImage = img.decodeImage(dogCropList);
```

The `dogCropImage` returned is null, then I realized that I should have been using `fromBytes` as the data I have is of type `List<int>` But the problem here is that `Image.fromBytes()` requires a `height` and `width` argument as well which I cannot know from the above list I populated,.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: I understood your technical problem but I didn't understand what you want to do. If you have an H x W where each pixel is represented by 4 positions, it is easy to know where you are editing, but at no time can you remove anything from the array, otherwise you lose the reference H x W.

Comment: I believe that is the challenge I am facing. I am trying to crop to content within my ``List``/``Image``. In python, if my image was a ``100x100`` size and I want to extract a portion from it, it would be as simple as ``image = image[20:60,20:60]`` but its not as easy here as all image data is stored as a List. I want to locate the non-zero content within the image and then crop to that. I hope I was able to explain my issue.

Comment: Ok, I got it. it is not that difficult, as soon as I have time I will post the answer. But basically it is: if there is a crop at the height, just remove the pixel number * 4 from the array, in the first position, if it is at the top, or in the last ones if it is at the bottom. If there is a crop in width, let's say your crop would be 5 pixels on the right and 10 pixels on the left. Then from 100, you have 85. You remove your first 5 * 4 from the array, skip 85, remove another 10 * 4 and so on until the end of the array. More or less, you may need to make some adjustments.

Comment: Images everywhere store their pixel data in a list/array format. Certain libraries just have features to interface with it using a 2D x/y language.

Comment: @ClaudioCastro, thanks for the comment but I would appreciate that answer when you have the time, as I am already having difficulty converting between ``Uint8List`` and ``Image`` as shown in the code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All images store their pixel data in a list/array format. Libraries just exist to translate x and y coordinates into array indices. The conversion is pretty straightforward:

```dart
int stride = width * bytesPerPixel;
int index = (y * stride) + (x * bytesPerPixel);
```

Using this, it's pretty simple to modify pixels in a list of bytes. For example:

```dart
for (int y = startY; y <= endY; y++) {
  int yStride = y * stride;
  for (int x = startX; x <= endX; x++) {
    int index = yStride + (x * bytesPerPixel);
    // Assuming an ARGB format
    pixelData[index]   = aValue;
    pixelData[index+1] = rValue;
    pixelData[index+2] = gValue;
    pixelData[index+3] = bValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but does not answer my question of cropping to content. Also in the answer, what would the values of ``width``? as I do not know the width of cropped content, what is the ``bytesPerPixel``?

Comment: I assume you have the starting and ending X and Y coordinates of the cropped content? And `bytesPerPixel` is what it says: how many bytes are stored per pixel of information. It will probably be either 3 (for RGB images) or 4 (for ARGB/RGBA images), but it ultimately depends on the image.